# Angular - variable undefined

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-services

I am writing a service but am encountering a problem.

The service contains a variable that is implementing an interface. When the service is first created the variable holds the value of undefined.

To explain it with less code I came up with the following example.

This is an interface.

```
interface objectWithSensors {
  sensor1: number[];
  sensor2: number[];
}
```

The service has a varaible of this type declared as:

```
private sensorObject: objectWithSensors;
```

At this point in time this object is undefined.

Is there a way to define it at this point (put an object in there that I can later modify) or should I change the interface to a class with public attributes?

Comment: You should initialize `sensorObject` with a value. You need to define a class that implements this interface. You then instantiate an object of this class, for example in your service's constrictor, or you use dependency injection to assign it.

Comment: That's how I was told to use interfaces in a conventional way as well. But from what I understand Angular uses them to make binding to properties more easy. Declaring a variable of that interface type makes it possible to do stuff like sensorObject.sensor1.push(1). In short the variable implements the interface and you do not need an entire class.

Comment: Right, but you can't define default values for members in an interface. You need to either create a class that implements the interface, which provides the default, or you need to provide the default values when instantiating the variable.

Answer (score 2):

Use a class if you want to have a default value. Otherwise, do something like that:

```
sensorObject.sensor1 = [];
sensorObject.sensor2 = [];
```

Comment: I am trying to prevent the use of Classes here. I was thinking the same about it as your second option but did not want to pollute the space I am declaring all attributes in. Guess I could also just put the instantiation in a function and call that before I need the variable.

Comment: You can do it as a one liner just like the other answer if you don't want a class but it gets annoying quickly if you have to build the whole object just to add default value every time you want to use it.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply instantiate the object:

```js
private sensorObject: objectWithSensors = {
  sensor1: [],
  sensor2: []
}
```

Comment: Trying to keep the space I use for declaring attributes as clean as possible. I just realized I could still use this technique by moving the instantiation to a function and call that before I use it.